# If $\sin( 2 \theta) = \cos( 3)$ and $\theta \leq 90°$, find $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Find $\theta\leq90°$ if 
$$\sin( 2 \theta) = \cos( 3)$$

I know that $\sin 2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos \theta$, or alternatively, $\theta = \dfrac{\sin^{-1}(\cos 3)}{2}$.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: 2 sin theta cos theta=cos 3

Comment: Do you mean $\cos (3\theta)$, or simply $\cos(3)$?

Comment: @cjferes i dont know edit here.

Comment: theta = sin^-1 (cos 3 )/2

Comment: Hint: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282x%29%3Dcos%283%29

Comment: cos(3) okay.@amWhy.

Comment: i didn't get the answer.only i got downvotes for correct question also

Comment: I added your work (shown in comments) to your post. Next time when you post a question, add those kind of thoughts to your post at the time of posting, okay? You've also gotten one upvote, burm1. Don't fret, most users try to help as best they can, but it is best to show some of your work along with your question, when you can.

Comment: okay.thank you @amWhy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin2\theta=\cos3^\circ=\sin87^\circ$$

$$\implies2\theta=180^\circ m+(-1)^m87^\circ\text{ where } m \text{ is any integer}$$

$$\implies\theta=90^\circ m+(-1)^m43.5^\circ$$

Check for even $m=2r$(say) and for odd $=2r+1$(say)

Find $m$ such that $\displaystyle\theta\le90^\circ$

---

Alternatively,
$$\cos3^\circ=\sin2\theta=\cos\left(90^\circ-2\theta\right)=\cos\left(2\theta-90^\circ\right)$$

$$\iff2\theta-90^\circ= 360^\circ n\pm3^\circ\text{ where } n \text{ is any integer}$$

$\displaystyle'+'\implies 2\theta= 360^\circ n+93^\circ\iff\theta=180^\circ n+46.5^\circ$

$\displaystyle'-'\implies 2\theta= 360^\circ n+87^\circ\iff\theta=180^\circ n+43.5^\circ$

Find $n$ such that $\displaystyle\theta\le90^\circ$

Comment: @burm1, Also find the edited answer

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve the problem: note that

$$\sin(2\theta)=\cos(3)=\sin(90-3)$$

But we know $\theta\leq90°$, so $2\theta\leq180°$. Then, two solutions are possible:

$$2\theta=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}90-3=87°&\Rightarrow&\theta_1=43.5°\\90+3=93°&\Rightarrow&\theta_2=46.5°\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: $\theta \le  90^{\circ} \implies   2\theta \le  180^{\circ}$, guess  there can be two possible solutions ?

Comment: Didn't notice that, you're right! Editing answer now...

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin{( 2 \theta)} = \cos{(3^{\circ})} \Rightarrow \sin{(2 \theta)}=\sin{ \left (90^{\circ} \pm 3^{\circ} \right )} \Rightarrow 2 \theta=90^{\circ} \pm 3^{\circ}+360^{\circ}k, k \in \mathbb{Z}  \\ \Rightarrow \theta=\left ( 45\pm\frac{3}{2}+180k \right )^{\circ}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\Rightarrow \theta=\left ( \frac{93}{2}+180k \right )^{\circ} \text{ or } \theta=\left ( \frac{87}{2}+180k \right )^{\circ}, \ \ \ k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Then you have to find a $\theta$ such that $\theta \leq 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: I understand that the problem means $3°$, as the assumption is given in degrees...

Comment: I edited my answer..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean $3^{\circ}$, here are the steps
$$ \sin 2\theta=\cos 3^{\circ} $$
$$ \arcsin(\sin 2\theta)=\arcsin(\cos 3^{\circ}) $$
$$ 2\theta=\arcsin(\cos 3^{\circ}) $$
$$ \theta=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(\cos 3^{\circ})=\frac{87^{\circ}}{2}=43.5^{\circ} $$

Comment: The OP has already posted that answer, in the comments, 5 minutes before your post.

Comment: =1/2arc sin(cos 3) how to proceed after that i dont know the method without using calculator

Comment: @amWhy, oops. Didn't see it. Typing latex on a phone is a bit time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted, $\theta = \dfrac{\sin^{-1}(\cos 3)}{2}$. Cosine of $3$ is in the second quadrant and is quite close to $-1$, and sine of something close to $-1$ is going to be in the fourth quadrant, hence this sine is going to be negative. Dividing by two doesn't change the sign, so the aswer is:

$$\theta = -\dfrac{180\sin^{-1}(\cos 3)}{2\pi}=-\dfrac{90\sin^{-1}(\cos 3)}{\pi}$$

(The factor of $\frac{180}{\pi}$ comes from the fact that we need to convert radians to degrees.)